# two array list in my adapter android studio

Tags: android, firebase

I have two different array list in one viewholder here is my code

```
public class ProfileAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfileAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Model>mCats;
    private List<Model>mDogs;

    public ProfileAdapter(Context context, List<Model> mCats,List <Model>mDogs) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mCats = mCats;
        this.mDogs = mDogs;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override

    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fotos_pet_profile, parent,false);
        return new ProfileAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Model model = mDogs.get(position);
        Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext()).load(model.getPetpicture()).into(holder.pet_image);
        holder.pet_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, PostDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("userid", model.getUserid());
                intent.putExtra("postid", model.getPostid());
                intent.putExtra("belong", model.getBelong());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        final Model model2 = mCats.get(position);
        Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext()).load(model.getPetpicture()).into(holder.pet_image);
        holder.pet_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, PostDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("userid", model2.getUserid());
                intent.putExtra("postid", model2.getPostid());
                intent.putExtra("belong", model2.getBelong());
                context.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDogs.size() + mCats.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView pet_image;
    public ViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        pet_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pet_image);

    }
    }

}
```

and here is my declaration for it i have error when i run my program

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
>
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)

Comment: Which is line 437 in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, In your onBindViewHolder can cause an java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException because both cat and dog use same position so if a size of cat and dog model is not equal it can cause an exception. Other problem is your getItemCount,  which you code can garantee that it will cause an exception because the size of getItemCount always higher than cat or dog model size even both model have same size. For example,  if your cat and dog have same size at 3(you can get 0 to 2) your getItemCount will return 6, so when position is 3 it will cause java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException.

P. S. Sorry for my English skill.